Either-or Implication Constraints for a Group of Non-negative Continuous or Integer Variables
I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications, where all $x_i$ are either non-negative continuous or integer variables, belonging to a set of $\textit{n}$ $x_i$'s where at most one is greater than zero and when it is so all the other remaining  $\textit{n-1}$ $x_i$'s must be equal to 0.

Oh crap, I have totally forgotten about it which is part of modelling 101. Thank you for pointing it out!

These are called SOS1 constraints:
$\text{SOS1}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ means that at most one $x_i$ can be positive.
Assuming that $0 \le x_i \le M_i$ for some constant $M_i$, you can linearize such constraints by introducing binary decision variables $y_i$ and imposing
\begin{align}
x_i &\le M_i y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_i y_i &\le 1 \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces the logical implication $x_i>0 \implies y_i = 1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} allows at most one $y_i$ to be $1$.

Out of curiosity, is it possible to do it with Big M? Thanks.

Sorry, I made a typo, I meant to do without Big M. Thanks

SOS1 uses specialized branching instead of big-M.

Understood, thank you for highlighting it.
